# Enabling Lightning Dialer

Tags: configuration, cti

I am in a European environment and an Unlimited Edition. I am sysAdmin and I am trying to enable Lightning Dialer([help info](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=voice_impl_enable.htm&type=5)). However, when I type Dialer in the Setup (step 1), I cannot see any option following these two simple steps:

> 1) From Setup, enter Dialer in the Quick Find box, then select **Dialer Settings**.
>
> 2) Enable Dialer.
>
> Optionally, enable personal voicemail,
>   prioritized call lists, voicemail drop, and other settings for your
>   org as well.

Is some that I am forgeting?

Comment: Do you have this feature bought from Salesforce?

Comment: dã.... you are right! I understood that for these Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions did not have cost! Wrong interpretation! Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Dialer is a paid service, i.e., you will need to pay additional cost to get this enabled for your Salesforce Org. If you don't have it, then you won't be able to see those options.

Referring to the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=voice_impl_enable.htm&type=5):

> Lightning Dialer is available for an additional cost as an add-on license.